# CRA Advanced Configurations from Terminal?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

How can I set Create React App advanced configuration options from the terminal?
For example: `TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix like shells like macOS or Linux you can set env vars in the shell by adding the variable in-front of your command:

```sh
$ TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true yarn start
```

or

```sh
$ TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true npm start
```

On Windows you can use the Unix sub system to help you use the same syntax (or so I'm told)

Comment: Thanks a million was going thru .env hell